Universal Deformation Ring of Elliptic Curves
I am currently reading Katz-Mazur's Arithmetic Moduli of Elliptic Curves, and in (5.3.2) it said to let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic $p>0$, $E_0$ be a supersingular elliptic curve over $k,$ and $E/W(k)[[T]]$ be its universal deformation.
I think $W(k)[[T]]$ here is isomorphic to the universal deformation ring, but I could not find a construction of this anywhere. Like I know it is the ring of Power series over the ring of Witt vectors, but how do they reflect the geometry of each individual elliptic curve? Moreover, what is special about the universal deformation and how is it constructed? Thanks in advance for any help.

As far as I know (and I would be happy to be corrected), giving an explicit Weierstrass equation for $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{univ}\to \mathrm{Spf}(W(k)[\![t]\!])$ (where I am using $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{univ}$ for the universal deformation) is quite messy.
That said, there is a way of getting a handle on $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{univ}$. Namely, recall the following celebrated theorem of Serre--Tate.

Theorem (Serre--Tate): Let $R$ be an $I$-adically complete ring and let $E_0$ be an elliptic curve over $R_0:=R/I$. Then, the map
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Deformations}\\ \mathcal{E}/
 \mathrm{Spf}(R) \text{ of }E_0\end{matrix}\right\}\to
 \left\{\begin{matrix}\text{Deformations}\\ H/
 \mathrm{Spf}(R) \text{ of }E_0[p^\infty]\end{matrix}\right\},$$ given
by $\mathcal{E}\mapsto \mathcal{E}[p^\infty]$ is a bijection.

The upshot of this is that to understand your universal deformation $\mathcal{E}^\mathrm{univ}$ you only need to understand the universal deformation $\mathcal{H}^\mathrm{univ}$ of $E_0[p^\infty]$. This is something that you can get a handle on by observations of Faltings (in this basic case, this must be much more classical, but I am not sure the precise lineage of ideas).
The first key step is the following result of Faltings--de Jong.

Theorem (Faltings--de Jong): There is a fully faithful embedding $$\mathbb{D}\colon \mathrm{BT}_p(W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!])\to \left
> \{(M,F,\mathrm{Fil}^1)\}\right\},$$ where the source is the category
of of $p$-divisible groups over $W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!]$ and the
latter is the category of triples $(M,F,\mathrm{Fil}^1)$, where

$M$ is a finite free $W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!]$-module,
$F\colon \phi^\ast M\to M$ is a $W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!]$-linear map, where $\sigma\colon W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!]\to
> W(k)[\![t_1,\ldots,t_n]\!]$ is the map given by the usual Frobenius on
$W(k)$ and with $\phi(t_i)=t_i^p$,
$\mathrm{Fil}^1\subseteq M$ is a direct summand. In fact, one can even describe the essential image explicitly.


(NB: I'm being a bit sneaky here. Really these triples should be quadruples, where we also give a $F$-horizontal connection $\nabla$ on $M$. That said, it's a beautiful observation of Faltings that specifically in this power series ring case one can always uniquely upgrade such a triple to such a quadruple. So, while I am not lying here, in some sense to describe the inverse image to $\mathbb{D}$ on its essential image, you need $\nabla$, and while one can in-theory give an explicit description of $\nabla$, it is definitely the most mysterious part!)
So, to describe $\mathcal{H}^\mathrm{univ}\in\mathrm{BT}_p(W(k)[\![t]\!])$ for you, I really only need to tell you the triple
$$\mathbb{D}(\mathcal{H}^\mathrm{univ})=(M^\mathrm{univ},F^\mathrm{univ},\mathrm{Fil}^{1,\mathrm{univ}}).$$
The following is then the beautiful observation of Faltings (with the disclaimer about correct lineage being applied here).

Proposition (Faltings): One has that

$M^\mathrm{univ}=W(k)[\![t]\!]^2$,
written in $\phi$-semilinear notation, $F=\begin{pmatrix}1 & t\\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ p & 0\end{pmatrix}$,
$\mathrm{Fil}^{1,\mathrm{univ}}=W(k)[\![t]\!]\cdot \begin{bmatrix}1\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$.


Notice here that the Frobenius and filtration are exactly coming from the filtered Dieudonne module associated to $E_0$, and the natural deformation of it to $W(k)$. So, this observation of Faltings says that the filtration is 'constant' in the family and that the Frobenius changes only from the constant one by the tautological unipotent element of $\mathrm{GL}_2(W(k)[\![t]\!])$.
(NB: Here is where the sneakiness mentioned before comes into play. The Frobenius and filtration are 'constant-esque', but the universal connection $\nabla^\mathrm{univ}$ is more complicated, even though it is uniquely determined by this data).
What Faltings really does is describe the universal deformations of a $p$-divisible group with Tate tensors, for which your example is a simple case (corresponding to $\mathcal{G}=\mathrm{GL}_2$, $\mu=(1,0)$, and $b=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\ p & 0\end{pmatrix})$. When you view things in this generality, the construction seems a lot less random. To read more about this, I highly suggest Wansu Kim's article Rapoport--Zink Spaces of Hodge Type.

Thank you for this great answer. I was aware of the work of Serre-Tate but I did not know the work of Faltings.
